# Format unmountable usb pendrive

Tags: usb-drive, usb-device, flash-memory

I believe someone else has already encountered this very same issue. Yet, I googled a lot and couldn't find my specific case.

Yesterday I created a "password reset disk" in Windows, using a pendrive.
Now I don't need it anymore and so I wanted to format it and use it in Fedora as I always did. But I can't.

The pendrive is not listed in gparted nor in "Disks" nor by `sudo fdisk -l`.

I can see it using `lsusb` and that's the only thing I can do by now.

The pendrive is not linked to any `/dev/sd#` and I fail to mount it because of that.

This is what `dmesg` says when I plug it in:

```
[ 6259.558560] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 6259.870317] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice=11.00
[ 6259.870340] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 6259.870345] usb 1-1: Product: Flash Disk
[ 6259.870349] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: USB
[ 6259.875607] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6259.876123] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 090c pid 1000: 400
[ 6259.876189] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
```

I don't believe it's broken because I did everything correctly yesterday and it correctly served its purpose. I can't access a Windows machine now, which might be the solution. But I can't believe I can't format this usb using my own Linux machine.

What do you suggest?

Comment: What does dmesg say after plugging your pendrive in your fedora box ?

Comment: This sounds similar to the sudden failure of a Kingston DTSE9 pendrive I had. It had a known flaw that can cause it to lose/corrupt its internal firmware. You might need to identify the particular controller chip used in your pendrive; a Windows software called "ChipGenius" can do that. Googling with the name of the controller chip, you might find out if that chip model is known for failures like that and if it is fixable with software, or not.

Comment: Do you happen to have an otg? Does your phone support otg? If yes, try plugging the usb to otg and to the phone. If the phone can read it you can format it from there. Not a solution, but if it works this way, you can format it.

Comment: I've edited the question so to add the dmesg output. I have got an otg but the phone doesn't give signal that something is connected (the otg works, I've tested it with another pendrive).
I can't say the brand of this pendrive. I got it from a conference I joined 1 year ago. In fact, this is a bit more than a pendrive, it's also a memory/gift of that conference... I hope I can save it. :(

Answer (score 0):

According to idVendor / idProduct reported by dmesg, your device could well be (if it is recent because these ids have been used by other manufacturers in the past) some SAMSUNG Flashdrive FIT.

According to dmesg, some quirk is being applied regarding this device. Quirks usually disable some capabilities / modify the way the standard driver will deal with the devices.

Depending on your current kernel version, it could be [this one](https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/3/10/422).

I did not investigate in order to understand precisely what it does but, it could well be inappropriate for what is your specific device in your own specific environment.

Therefore, I suggest that you reboot having this quirk (or any other one applying to this device) disabled.

I usually do that by editing /usr/src/linux/drivers/usb/core/quirks.c and commenting the associated lines. And rebuild the kernel.

It is possible that your distro provides some more handy way.

Comment: Recompiling the kernel...? I feel panic at the idea of doing that... o.o